# Directive not shown in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the following directive in a typescript file:

ProjectDirectivs.ts

```
/// <reference path="../module.ts"/>

module BalancingApp.App.Directives {
    angular.module('balancingApp')
    .directive('wbProject', function() {
        return {
            template: "<p>Projectdetails</p>"
        };
    })
    ;
}
```

When I call it inside of a template for a project detail page

ProjectDetailPage.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Projekt Details">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Projekt Details</h1>
        <div wbProject>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

it has no effects, there seems just to be empty space below the heading.

Do I do something wrong? How can I test if the wbProject directive actually is used?

If I edit the typescript file and insert errors, the whole page keeps in loading stage, so it seems that the file gets actually used and is not ignored.

Comment: you should use `wb-project` not `wbProject` in your template

Comment: This solved it! Add a question and I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular converts the directive name into [camel-case](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider) in template, so you should use `wb-project` instead of `wbProject` in template

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 angular.module('balancingApp')
    .directive('wbProject', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: "<p>Projectdetails</p>"
        };
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.. Again only the heading visible